# Why 'NOT LIKE' does not work with OR in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Why below query does not return CategoryName and Description excluding the record whose Description starts with S and D. But when I replace OR with AND it works.

```
SELECT CategoryName, Description
FROM [Categories]
Where Description NOT LIKE 'S%'
OR Description NOT LIKE 'D%'
```

Comment: It does work.  But you really want `AND`.

Comment: I wanted to know the reason why it does not return records whose description does not start from S and D. 
You can use the above query here https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_distinct

Comment: Because ("doesn't start with S" OR "doesn't start with D") describes every possible string in existence: Strings that start with S indeed do not start with D, and vice versa.

Answer (score 2):

You really want `AND` instead of `OR`.  But in SQL Server this is more simply written as:

```
Where Description NOT LIKE '[DS]%'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I am more interested to know about the reason why multiple not like dont work with OR condition.
If I use AND or something like below it works as expected 

SELECT CategoryName, Description FROM [Categories]
Where NOT (Description LIKE 'S%'
OR Description LIKE 'D%')

Comment: @AjeetMalviya . . . `NOT LIKE` works fine.  The problem is `OR`.  You want `AND`.

Comment: @AjeetMalviya give him the tick :).

Answer (score 0):

The reason it doesn't work is you are dealing with boolean logic.

Your query is asking if it is  'not like apples or not like oranges'

OR means both boolean statements need to be false in order to be false (or either needs to be true to be true) depending on your point of view.

if you have an apple it is not like and orange so your boolean logic is 1 or 0 which results in 1 or true.

That is why you want and so you need bothe to be 1 to pass the boolean logic.

Answer (score 0):

Taking SQL out of this, this is a classic application of [DeMorgan's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

In this case, it looks like you want "Descriptions that start with neither S nor D". Translating that into Boolean logic, that's:

```
(Description NOT «start with S») AND (Description NOT «start with D»)
```

Which is equivalent to

```
NOT ((Description «start with S») OR (Description «start with D»))
```

In this case, each of the two statements that I'm saying are equivalent is easily translated to SQL - use whichever of them makes the most sense.

Answer (score -1):

It would be nice if you could just stick some wildcards in the in clause like this:

```
where column1 not in ('%value1%','%value2%','%value3%')
```

But, you can’t stick a wildcard inside of the IN clause. So, here is the easiest solution.

```
select *
from table1
where column1 not like '%value1%'
and column1 not like '%value2%'
and column1 not like'%value3%';
```

Basically you are trying to replace in ( value1 **AND** value2 **AND** value3 )

with OR logical operator,
That is why this will not work.

after you replace OR with AND you should get this results:

[image: Code Snipp]

[Link to full description of the problem and the solution](https://www.sqltrainingonline.com/sql-not-like-with-multiple-values/)

Comment: please avoid using link only explanations. you should but the text in the post and provide link to attribute.